# 99% Regex for matching URLs (but not ones inside of anchor tags)

Tags: regex, url, tags, anchor

Can anyone help with this regex? It's 99% of the way there. Just a really weird couple of failing tests.

For: "http://www.server.com" and "http://www.server.com "
The regex matches the "http://www.server.co"
I'm inferring it should fail the match because of the lookahead for the closing tag.

```
(?<!(?:>\s*)|(?:href="")) (?# Anti-Anchor Tag)
(?:(?:https?|ftp)://) (?# Protocol)
(?# Username/Password intentionally left out)
(?:
    (?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}) (?# Exclude 10.X.X.X)
    (?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}) (?# Exclude 127.X.X.X)
    (?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}) (?# Exclude 169.254.X.X)
    (?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}) (?# Exclude 192.168.X.X)
    (?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}) (?# Exclude 172.X.X.X)
    (?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]) (?# IP address)
)|(?:
    (?:[\w\d\u00a1-\uffff]+-?)*[\w\d\u00a1-\uffff]+) (?# First part of host)
    (?:\.(?:[\w\d\u00a1-\uffff]+-?)*[\w\d\u00a1-\uffff]+)* (?# Middle parts of host)
    \.[\w\d\u00a1-\uffff]+ (?# Last part of host)
)
(?::\d{2,5})? (?# Port number)
(?:/[^\s\?#]*)? (?# Folders & Files)
(?:\?[^\s#]*)? (?# Query String)
(?:\#\S*)? (?# Fragment)
(?!\s*</a>) (?# Anti-Closing Anchor Tag)
```

btw this is a modified version of @diegoperini found at https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: I would think twice if it is really needed to use regex for that...

Comment: Could you please add your regex flavor? Looks like .NET/C#